# subsequences examples

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if it is possible for a sequence to have a strictly increasing subsequence and a subsequence that converges to 0. I think there is such a sequence and an example would be $a_n$ = $n$/($n$ + $1$). Am I correct?

Comment: Again, nothing difficult here: a_n = -1/n

Comment: Your sequence does not converve to $0$, more importantly it converges to $1$. Therefore it can't have subsequences converging to $0$.

Comment: Just make two sequences, and combine them together somehow.

Comment: @fretty It's customary, when addressing someone other than the OP, to precede the message with $@\text{ name}$, like I did here.

Comment: @fretty Isn't $a_n$ = $-1$/$n$ a decreasing sequence?

Comment: @mespebjidom: It's increasing. $-1<-\frac{1}{2}<\cdots<0$.

Comment: @mespebjidom: no...

Comment: @fretty My mistake I didn't notice that it is -1/n and not 1/n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 0 & \mbox{if} &n \text{ is odd}, \\ 2n & \mbox{if} & n \text{ is even}. \end{array} \right.$$

The formula for this sequence is $a_n=n+(-1)^n n$.

Comment: I like the $a_n$ = $-1/n$ example though.